# Button not styling

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-widget, dashboard

I have a single button that I inserted dynamically in a dashboard pattern that I implemented.
In the onCreate method I create my button and insert in my dashboard(named **MainMenu**):

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
Rect rect = new Rect();
rect.set(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());
dr.setBounds(rect);
button = new ImageButton(this);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("home_button", "style", getPackageName());
button.setId(i+1);
mainMenu.addView(button);
```

This is my style in styles.xml:

```
 <style name="home_button">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">"Some Text"</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff29549f</item>
</style>
```

When I get the style from getIdentifier, a Resources.NotFoundException is thrown. And the message is:

> Requesting resource 0x7f060000 failed because it is complex

And my button doesn't appears.
Sorry if I extended myself, but anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: You sure you want to have both gravity and layout_gravity in the button? Try leaving attributes out of the style and see which one is causing you trouble.

Comment: Hi Christine. Tried your solution, but didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you apply the style directly to the button in the layout XML. Then hide the button until you need to show it.

Comment: Hi azgolfer. It's a possibility. I'll try it and post the results. I have the same problem when I insert drawable in button. This behavior is very strange.

Comment: I solved partially. When I insert a layout with a drawable works fine,  the button appears with the image. The previous problem still remains.